# Extending custom webcomponent

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I'm having some trouble extending a custom webcomponent onto another.
I'm currently getting the following error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: LinkedProducts is not defined**

I have two classes, in each of their files. And they are both included in the build with Parcel, I can inspect in the compiled JS that they exist, and `LinkedProducts` do come before `ProductItem` in the build.

```js
class LinkedProducts extends HTMLElement {
 constructor() {
  super();
 }
}

customElements.define('linked-products', LinkedProducts);
```

```js
class ProductItem extends LinkedProducts {
 constructor() {
  super();
 }
}

customElements.define('product-item', ProductItem);
```

**Where do I go wrong on this?**

Comment: Make sure that the LinkedProducts is defined before the ProductItem

Comment: @Johan It is, I can see it in the final JS build that it comes way before the reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about order:

```js
class LinkedProducts extends HTMLElement {
 constructor() {
  super();
 }
}

customElements.define('linked-products', LinkedProducts);
class ProductItem extends LinkedProducts {
  connectedCallback(){
    this.innerHTML = "Hello " + this.nodeName;
  }
}

customElements.define('product-item', ProductItem);
```

```html
<product-item></product-item>
```

Or compacter/different:

```js
customElements.define('linked-products', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback(){
    this.innerHTML = "Hello " + this.nodeName;
  }
});

customElements.define('product-item', 
  class extends customElements.get("linked-products") {});
```

```html
<product-item></product-item>
```

Comment: That is how the ordering is.
I guess it's Parcel that bundles it, so the reference ordre gets lost? I can see it in the correct order in the bundled JS, so guess that's it then...